# Inserting field for current date/time in Google Slides

Tags: google-slides

Is there a way to insert the current date and/or time in Google Slides?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case someone else finds this, I was able to automate this using Google Apps Scripts which is available under the Tools menu. Here is the script I made which updates any text box that has the description field set to "$date" to the current date every time the presentation is opened.

```
function onOpen() {
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "PST", "M/d/yyyy"); 
  var pattern = "\\b\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4}\\b"; 
  var slides = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides();
  var slidesLength = slides.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < slidesLength; i++) {  
    var shapes = slides[i].getShapes();
    var shapesLength = shapes.length;
    for (var j = 0; j < shapesLength; j++) {
      if (shapes[j].getDescription() == "$date") {
        var textRange = shapes[j].getText();
        textRange.clear();
        textRange.insertText(0, date);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Using this onOpen() fails at SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides(), presumably because getActivePresentation() can't run in AuthMode.NONE when the slide deck loads. I cannot figure out how to get it to run on open as per https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2017/12/07/6-deadly-sins-google-apps-script-add-on/ even tho I modified the GoodIntegratedApp example and put it outside the onOpen() function.